# Best way to transfer iPod videos to computer?

Tags: macos, mac, itunes, ipod, video

What is the best way to transfer the videos that I take with my iPod nano to the computer? The iPod storage is slowly filling up, so I'd like to remove the videos from it.

It looks like I can just use the Finder, go to DCIM/000APPLE and get the .MP4 files from there? Do I need to transfer the .DAT files as well?

But I can't believe that is the only way to get the videos to the computer. If I copy them manually from the iPod and then remove them on the i{od, the next videos I take will automatically be named IMG0000.MP4, ..., again, which means next time I'll have to move them to a different directory on my computer, in order not to overwrite them, so it's going to be messy and hard to organize...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3822) they recommend either using iPhoto or iMovie to import the files for use elsewhere. An alternative is to use a program like [Clipstart](http://www.riverfold.com/software/clipstart/) to import and manage your videos.